# MVC page that displays one model but let's you create a different one

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the right way to create an input of a different model type for a MVC page?  I could just put in the HTML that I needed, but how do you do it the idiomatic way with "Html.EditorFor" etc.

For example, in Stack overflow, you are looking at a post, but at the bottom you are creating an answer.  Should an IEnumerable be part of the post model?

Answer (score 1):

You can include both models in the view model for the page. For example, let's say you are viewing a post and want to allow users to comment on the post. Your view model for the page would look like this:

```
public class ViewPostViewModel
{
    // The view model for the post and replies
    public PostViewModel Post { get; set; }

    // The view model for the comment form
    public AddCommentViewModel Comment { get; set; }
}
```

This is my preferred method of including two view models in the same page, especially if you will need to reuse one of the view models across several different action methods.

Then in your view you can use the standard `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Comment.Message)` helpers to create the form inputs, or render the comment form using a partial view.

Answer (score 0):

Use partials views, then you can have something like this:

Your partial:

```
@model stackoverflow.answer

@HTML.desplaynamefor(u => u.name)
```

Then in another view you can do this

```
@model stackoverflow.post

@HTML.displaynamefor(u => u.comment)

@partial("mypartial",new answer())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only create a new answer without data coming from he server side (no server side validation, editing, etc.), you could just instantiate the model and then use a partial view for the answer form like this:

QuestionView:

```
@model ViewModel.Question
@{ var answer = new ViewModel.Answer(); }

<h3>Question:</h3>
@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Text)

@Html.Partial("AnswerFormView", answer)
```

AnswerFormView:

```
@model ViewModel.Answer
@using (var form = Html.BeginForm(...))
{
   <h3>Answer:</h3>
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Text)
}
```

If you however need data from server side (validation, default values, editing, etc.) you'll need to get the data from the controller and use a composition view.

ViewModel.Composed:

```
public class Composed
{
   public ViewModel.Question Question { get; set; }
   public ViewModel.Answer Answer { get; set; }
}
```

ComposedView:

```
@model ViewModel.Composed

@Html.Partial("QuestionView", Model.Question)
@Html.Partial("AnswerFormView", Model.Answer)
```

QuestionView:

```
@model ViewModel.Question
<h3>Question:</h3>
@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Text)
```

AnswerFormView:

```
@model ViewModel.Answer
@using (var form = Html.BeginForm(...))
{
   <h3>Answer:</h3>
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Text)
}
```